# Injecting an Immutable object and a factory object

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, dependency-injection

Please see the code below (contained in an IEnumerable method):

```
int Quantity = (int)Math.Floor(ChangeRequired / CurrencyAmount);
ChangeDenomination = ChangeDenominationsFactory.Create(CurrencyAmount, Quantity);
yield return ChangeDenomination;

ChangeRequired = ChangeRequired - (ChangeDenomination.Amount * ChangeDenomination.Quantity);
```

ChangeDenominationsFactory and ChangeDenomination are injected into the constructor.

As you can see the ChangeDenomination class has a zero arguments constructor - it is immutable.

I am using Castle Windsor.  There are two ways I can set this up:

1) Introduce a zero arguments constructor into ChangeDenomination specifically for Castle Windsor.
2) Configure Castle Windsor so that ChangeDenomination is given the necessary arguments as follows:

```
Component.For<IDenomination, Denomination>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("amount", 0.0M), Dependency.OnValue("quantity", 0))
```

Both approaches work as expected.  Which way is "best practice".

Comment: Can you explain why you need a factory and injection? That seems to be a lot of overhead for a small, immutable object. Why not just ` = new ChangeDenomination(CurrencyAmount, Quantity);`?

Comment: And why does your DIC know about the concrete class, when it also provides a factory, so you don't need to know the actual class?

Comment: Which approach makes the most sense for you and your specific situation?  See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354

Comment: @nvoigt , thanks for your comment.  I have removed the concrete class that is injected.  The reason I have used IOC is consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would inject `ChangeDenominationFactory` only.  The factory would then use a traditional `new` construct to instantiate the immutable `ChangeDenomination` object.

It is perfectly OK for this sort of pattern to co-exist with DI and Castle Windsor.  Factories get a pass, as their single responsibility *is* construction of objects. If the factory itself has any dependencies, *those* should be injected into the factory, so that you can isolate and unit test.

A drawback here is that it's a little harder to unit test `ChangeDenomination`, because you can't isolate away the constructor logic.  That's probably OK, as long as the constructor doesn't depend on anything other than the constructor arguments.  It sounds like that is the case, since you aren't injecting anything into it.

So my answer is

3) Don't register `ChangeDenomination` with your IoC container at all.

If you want to be a purist and have a problem with this because you think it is "inconsistent," I am curious how you plan to use your IoC container to instantiate other immutable objects, such as `string` :)